# How to compare various VARCHAR as numbers in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, entity-attribute-value

I have a table with various number formats like:

- 2
- 3.44189
- 4,1
- -0.0022
- 9.9E+37
- 1.9E-12

these are measurements in a varchar2 column and to each measurement there is a specification with upper and lower limit value (in same format),
so what i want are measurements in between these borders

```
SELECT VALUE, LOW, HIGH FROM MEASUREMENTS
WHERE to_number(replace(VALUE,',','.'), '999999999D99999999999999999999999999999999999999','NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,''')
    > to_number(replace(LOW,',','.'), '999999999D99999999999999999999999999999999999999','NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,''')
AND   to_number(replace(VALUE,',','.'), '999999999D99999999999999999999999999999999999999','NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,''') 
    <=to_number(replace(HIGH,',','.'), '999999999D99999999999999999999999999999999999999','NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,''')
```

these query works for every number writing above, except exponential numbers like 9.9E+37. 
I found a rewriting with TO_CHAR, but it doesnt work with varchar

Have anybody a solution to compare various numbers stored as varchar with each other?
thx

Comment: Why are you storing them as varchar? Anytime you design to do conversions in code later, your design is flawed.

Comment: Don ***NOT*** store numbers as `varchar`. Just don't

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you know they are all numbers, I would suggest using `cast()`:

```
select cast(col as float)
```

Comment: @JaMaBing that doc you reference is the [javadb](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html) doc and not oracle.  `select cast('4.1' AS float) from dual;` works just fine in the Oracle RDBMS.